# EMC Networker and symbolic links

Tags: backup, symbolic-link, emc, networker

When investigating EMC Networker setup, I found a strange issue.

I have a job set up to save /oracle from a server. On that server, /oracle is a symbolic link to /TEMPORAL/oracle

When I check the status of the backup job, it says it has saved /TEMPORAL/oracle and so the automatic checkings I have to compare the scheduled backups and the completed ones fail, since "/oracle" and "/TEMPORAL/oracle" are not the same string.

How to make EMC Networker report the saveset I have requested even if it is a symbolic link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetWorker does not do well with symlinks in the saveset.  According to p.68 of the 8.1 Administrator's Guide, "If the save set name includes a symbolic link, a
save set recovery is not supported."

I would recommend switching your saveset name to use the link target name (in your case`/TEMPORAL/oracle`) to insure you can recover consistently *and* if you have an issue you will be supported.